# Необходимые ресурсы для работы с varchar2(32767) и varchar2(20)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть ли разница в затрачиваемых ресурсах, размер отводимой памяти, количество машинного времени?

Конечно, речь о случае, когда обе переменные содержат одинаковое кол-во данных:

```
declare
  a  varchar2(32767) := 'Hello, World!';
  b  varchar2(20)    := 'Hello, World!';
begin
  --TODO
end;
```

Comment: Вопрос возник из экспериментов по обработке в цикле большого количества переменных. Разницы я не заметил. Да и количество отводимой памяти, насколько я понимаю, зависит только от количества символов. Но хочется подтверждения с точки зрения теории. Пишу пакет, где не хотелось бы ограничивать его пользователя, но и не хочется попасть в ситуацию бессмысленного расхода ресурсов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разницы, ни в производительности, ни в затрачиваемых ресурсах, нет.

Приведённая в скобках макс. длина строчного значения, это только ограничение (*constraint*). Ресурсы будут выделяться в зависимости от актуального значения динамически.

Если согласно условиям задачи, для символьных значений никаких ограничений не предусматренно, то чтобы не указывать для каждой переменной ограничение, которое часто выбирается: "Да вроде больше, чем 20 символов не будет" (*принцип - авось*),  лучше объявитъ свой тип данных для строк без ограничений:

```
declare
    subtype longvarchar is varchar2 (32767);
    s longvarchar := 'Hello, World!';
begin 
    s := rpad (s, 32767, 'X');
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```